# Colors in emacs buffer list

Tags: emacs, emacs24

Hi how can I colorize the emacs buffer menu, I'd like to have different colors for different type of files. That should make it easier to navigate a large list of buffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered ibuffer  which had all the features i needed .. thanks

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode

Answer (score 7):

Try <kbd>M-x</kbd>`ibuffer`.  It can serve as a replacement for `list-buffers`(<kbd>C-x C-b</kbd>), with a wealth of extra functionalities for filtering, sorting, etc.  After invocation, use <kbd>C-h m</kbd> for more details.

Comment: `h` for help is quicker than  `C-h m`

Answer (score 3):

See [EmacsWiki](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/BufferMenu), it contains some links to enhanced buffer menus.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can find your best Keybind:

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'buffer-menu)

instead `C-x C-b` if you have another better choice.